# Sharing core data between apps

Tags: ios, core-data

Just a quick question. Is it possible to share the core data from one app with another? i.e. The first app has it's own core data, continually being populated, but when the second totally different app is downloaded it uses the first apps core data instead of it's own.

If it can, how would I do it?

Comment: Not with core data only, you would need some kind of server storage that both apps can communicate with

Comment: OK, that's not the answer I was hoping for, I can do the SOAP requests to a server, get the returned data and PARSE the results and save them in CoreData...... but I'd rather have apps talking to each other and passing information between each other. Can you not think of any way this can be done?

Comment: Thinking about this, I'm pretty sure I downloaded an IOS mySQL or something similar app a while ago that could access databases on my phone, and display a read only results. I can't for the life of me remember what it was called! Surely if I have produced the first app, I know the Model description, I could use that model in my second app?

Comment: Thanks Joakim, I ended up using SOAP requests in the end. Works as expected.